# How to multiply two polynomial lists in scheme

Tags: scheme

I am looking for tips on how to multiply two polynomial lists, e.g how to create a function 
 (poly_mul '(3 4 5)'(5 9 6 2)) the output should be (15 47 79 75 38 10)

What i have so far:

```
(define (poly-mul lst1 lst2)
(let loop ((expo 0) (l1 lst1) (l2 lst2))
(cond ((null? l1) '())
      ((null? l2) (loop expo (cdr l1) lst2))
      (else (cons (* (car l1) (car l2))
                  (loop expo l1 (cdr l2)))))))
```

Comment: [Oh!](https://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) Even John McCarthy was stumped by this problem once.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at `poly-mult` as a recursive `poly-add`. Given the easy-to-implement `poly-add`.

```
(define (poly-add p1 p2)
  (cond ((empty? p1)
         p2)
        ((empty? p2)
         p1)
        (else
         (cons (+ (car p1)
                  (car p2))
               (poly-add (cdr p1)
                         (cdr p2))))))
```

You could implement `poly-mult` like this using a helper procedure, `raise`.

```
(define (poly-mul p1 p2 (e 0))
  (if (empty? p1)
      empty
      (poly-add (raise e (map (curry * (car p1)) p2))
                (poly-mul (cdr p1)
                          p2
                          (+ e 1)))))

(define (raise e p)
  (if (= e 0)
      p
      (cons 0
            (raise (- e 1)
                   p))))

(poly-mul '(3 4 5) '(5 9 6 2))
;; '(15 47 79 75 38 10)
```

By defining `raise` as an external procedure it's easy to see how we raise polynomials to the next power. However, we could keep this behavior contained inside `poly-mult` by using a loop and making the exponent (`e`) a function itself.

```
(define (poly-mul p1 p2)
  (let loop ((p p1)         ;; polynomial
             (e identity))  ;; exponent
    (if (empty? p)
        empty
        (poly-add (e (map (curry * (car p)) p2))
                  (loop (cdr p)
                        (compose (curry cons 0) e))))))

(poly-mul '(3 4 5) '(5 9 6 2))
;; '(15 47 79 75 38 10)
```

Lastly, using a loop in `poly-mult` makes it easy for us to convert the recursive call to a proper tail call. The `poly-add` operation now happens first and the updated accumulator (`acc`) is given to the next loop iteration.

```
(define (poly-mul p1 p2)
  (let loop ((acc empty)   ;; accumulator
             (p p1)        ;; polynomial
             (e identity)) ;; exponent
    (if (empty? p)
        acc
        (loop (poly-add acc
                        (e (map (curry * (car p)) p2)))
              (cdr p)
              (compose (curry cons 0) e)))))
```

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602072/how-to-multiply-two-polynomial-lists-in-scheme#comment94099918_53602072). :)

Comment: Really nice, thanks for sharing. I was searching for a simpler way to do the `(cons 0 ...)` and this is great. I now see the beautiful bird :)

Comment: catch, and release... :)

Comment: in your last version, you can avoid the repeated `cons 0`s by having a second accumulator, a reversed prefix, and returning `(revappend pfx acc)` in the end. In Haskell syntax, `multpoly p1 p2 = go [] [] p1
   where {
   go pfx acc [] = revappend pfx acc ;
   go pfx acc (a1:p1) = 
     let { p = addpoly acc (map (a1*) p2) }
     in go (cons (car p) pfx) (cdr p) p1 }`

Answer (score 0):

You found a way to multiply numbers. Now you need to add them with shifted indexes, like you would on paper:

```
 15 27 18 06 00 00
 00 20 36 24 08 00
 00 00 25 45 30 10
```

It would be much easier to do with vectors, with list you can e.g. append zeros as you sum:

```
(define polynomial-mul
  (lambda (lst1 lst2)    
    (let ((tmp 
           (map (lambda (n) 
              (map (lambda (m) 
                     (* n m)) 
                   lst2)) lst1)))
      (let loop ((z '(0)) (l (car tmp)) (r (cdr tmp)))
        (cond
         ((null? r) l)
         (else
          (loop (cons 0 z) 
                (map + 
                     (append l '(0))
                     (append z (car r)))
                (cdr r))))))))
```

But this is very inefficient because of append. It's better to use auxilliary function to shift two lists:

```
(define shifted-map
  (lambda (f shift lst1 lst2)
    (cond
     ((and (not (null? lst1)) (not (zero? shift))) 
      (cons (car lst1) 
            (shifted-map f (sub1 shift) (cdr lst1) lst2)))
     ((null? lst2) lst1)
     (else
      (cons (f (car lst1) (car lst2))
            (shifted-map f shift (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))))))

(define polynomial-mul
  (lambda (lst1 lst2)    
    (let ((tmp 
           (map (lambda (n) 
              (map (lambda (m) 
                     (* n m)) 
                   lst2)) lst1)))
      (let loop ((shift 1) (l (car tmp)) (r (cdr tmp)))
        (cond
         ((null? r) l)
         (else
          (loop  
           (add1 shift)
           (shifted-map + shift l (car r))
           (cdr r))))))))
```

Comment: `shifted-map` is dangerous as it's written here. For example `(shifted-map + 1 empty empty)` is in the domain but throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

With SRFI-1's `fold-right`, it is a scale-shift-and-add loop from the right, just as in high school math:

```
(require srfi/1)

(define (multpoly p1 p2)
  (fold-right
      (lambda (a r)
         (addpoly (map (lambda (b) (* a b)) p2)  ; map (a*) p
                  (cons 0 r)))
      '() p1))
```

where

```
(define (addpoly p1 p2)
  (cond ((null? p1) p2)
        ((null? p2) p1)
        (else (cons (+       (car p1) (car p2))
                    (addpoly (cdr p1) (cdr p2))))))
```